# How to replace word in array of text in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, nlp, stemming

I want to stem my text with my own array:

```py
word_list1 = ["cccc", "bbbb", "aaa"]

def stem_text(text):
     text = text.split()
     array = np.array(text)
     temp = np.where(array == word_list1, word_list1[0], array)
     text = ' '.join(temp)
     return text
```

I want to do like this:

for all of the word in `word_list1`, check the text and if some word matched, replace it with `word_list[0]`

Comment: provide expected output

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar how can I do it? I'm new in python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use list comprehension

```
word_list1 = ["cccc", "bbbb", "aaa"]

def stem_text(text):
    text = text.split()
    temp = [word_list1[0] if i in word_list1 else i for i in text]
    text = ' '.join(temp)
    return text

stem_text("hello bbbb now aaa den kkk")
```

Output :

```
'hello cccc now cccc den kkk'
```

Comment: You might consider using a set for `word_list1` for the check within the list comprehension. Otherwise you need to go through the whole list of words `word_list1` on each iteration, which might become pretty slow for larger word list sizes.

Answer (score 0):

```
word_list1 = ["cccc", "bbbb", "aaa"]

def stem_text(text):
  text = text.split()

  for keyword in word_list1:
    text.replace(keyword, word_list1[0])

  text = ' '.join(temp)
  return text
```

You can just run a replace on it. If it exists (`if keyword in text`) it will replace. But if it doesn't exist the replace function will do nothing so that's fine too. So the if condition is not necessary.

Answer (score -1):

Let's say you have a list of words you want to replace with "cccc" and a string where you want to find those words and replace them.

```
words_to_replace = [...]
word_list1 = ["cccc", "bbbb", "aaa"]
string = 'String'
for word in words_to_replace:
   new_string = string.replace(word, words_list1[0])
   string = new_string
```